# How to wrap selected code in brackets/parentheses in Visual Studio 2022

Tags: visual-studio, ide, visual-studio-2022, code-editor

In VS Code and JetBrains IDEs, when you select (highlight) a snippet of code and press an opening key for brackets (`{` or `[`) or parentheses (`(`), it wraps the selected text. **Visual Studio**, however, *deletes the selected snippet*, or better, replaces it by the pressed character. Is there a way to configure it to the more intelligent behaviour of VS Code and JetBrains? I browsed "Text Editor" settings but didn't find any that seemed to do this:
[image]

Comment: Send a feedback suggestion so the product team prioritizes this higher!  It's currently not available in plain VS.

Comment: Did it, thank you. What a shame for VS...

Comment: In version 17.4.4 Professional this is on by default - and I want to turn it *off*.  I have not found a setting for it.